# Angular 2 @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.3 Errors

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I was just trying to migrate the router in my project to the latest @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.3 but when I try to compile it in visual studio I am receiving the below errors:

```
Type expected.  TypeScript router_state.d.ts
Type expected.  url_tree.d.ts
Type expected.  tree.d.ts
```

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/angular/vladivostok/issues/39

Comment: Yes you are right. The new router looks promising but dependency on nightly builds of TypeScript is stopping us from trying it.